# Express special function (Hypergeometric1F1) in terms of another special function (HermiteH)

Tags: replacement, special-functions

I have the following Mathematica expression:

```
(2^k Gamma[1/2 + k] Hypergeometric1F1[-k, 1/2, t^2/2])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
```

where k is an integer and t is a real number, and I would like to express it replacing the hypergeometric function with Hermite Polynomials, using the well known relation:

```
Hypergeometric1F1[-k, 1/2, x] -> HermiteH[2*k, Sqrt[x]]*k!/(2*k)!*(-1)^k
```

Of course I can do it manually, but I need to manipulate the expression in Mathematica afterward. I googled for a long time but could not find how to do it. Any help?

Comment: What prevents you from manipulating the expression in Mathematica after replacing it manually as you have shown?

Comment: Nothing of course, but I would like to learn how to do it without having to do it manually.